# Conditional error in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following commands in my MakeFile:

```
.PHONY: lint
lint:
    eslint src --ext ts

.PHONY: component
component:
ifndef name
$(error name is not set. try 'make component name=')
endif
```

The issue is when I run `make lint`, or any other command, make exits with the error found in `component`.

How would I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make expands the `ifndef …` block as part of parsing the makefile. It could expand to targets or commands. You wrote “if `name` is not defined, generate an error” so Make does what you instructed.

It seems that you meant to write a rule for the `component` target. If so, you need to change the parse-time error into a run-time error.

```
component:
ifdef name
        command_to_generate_component $(name)
else
        false "Error: name is not set. Try 'make component name=…'"
endif
```